# Command-line web browser with Kerberos authentication?

Tags: command-line, authentication, browser, kerberos

**QUESTION:** Is there a Kerberos-friendly web browser usable via an SSH console?

I have tried [links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_%28web_browser%29) but it does not seem to work with Kerberos (the webapp asks me for login/password even though I have a valid Kerberos ticket (which I got with `kinit`).

**CONTEXT**:

From my laptop I have command-line access to a server, and need to browse an intranet webapp hosted on that server, using Kerberos authentication.

The server can not ping the laptop, so I can not run Firefox on the server and redirect the DISPLAY to my laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are connected to this server using SSH, you may use "ssh -x" then X will be automatically forwarded (and secured).

Answer (score 3):

Use ssh as a SOCKS proxy. Pass `-D 1080` to `ssh` and specify `localhost:1080` on your spiffy GUI web browser that supports SOCKS and Kerberos.